# Include systemd-journal-remote with Bitbake

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded, systemd-journald

I am using an embedded Linux system based on Yocto/Open Embedded Linux and the systemd-journald-remote program is missing.

When I look at the [systemd recipe](http://%20http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd_244.5.bb?h=dunfell) the program is mentioned. It seems like it is not compiled or added by default to the image. I understand how to add normal recipes but unfortunately I don't understand how to add such a "subpackage".

The Bitbake documentation is unfortunately overwhelming for a beginner like me. Can someone help me?

Comment: `IMAGE_INSTALL += "systemd-journal-remote"`?

Answer (score 0):

Create bbappend for systemd in your meta-layer with following path `recipes-core/systemd/systemd_%.bbappend` and:

```
PACKAGECONFIG_append = " \
    microhttpd \
"
```

Comment: Hi Oleksandr. Can you explain why I should set this? microhttpd is needed but should be auto included?

Comment: I don't remember this quesion. It's been six months. Why don't you try it first?

Comment: I tried without success. I try to understand this setting

Comment: No sarcasm intended, but how come it took you six months to try this?

Comment: The project is not a high priority and lately it has been burning in other places, so I (unfortunately) didn't find time for it. In addition, home offices have not made things any easier.

Comment: The dependency to microhttpd seems to be fixed upstream: https://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd_255.1.bb#n433

Answer (score 0):

You can add it into your image `.bb` or `.bbappend` file with following parameter:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "systemd-journal-remote"
```

This will add `systemd-journal-remote` into your image. Install the image on your target board, log in to your target and configure the file `/etc/systemd/journal-remote.conf`.

Then, enable the service with `systemctl enable systemd-journal-remote`, and then restart it with `systemctl restart systemd-journal-remote`.