# Bitbake how to compile a package split

Tags: yocto, bitbake, yocto-recipe

The systemd recipe provides via a package split multiple packages, like `systemd-journal-remote`, see https://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-core/systemd/systemd_255.1.bb#n397

How do I compile `systemd-journal-remote` and introspect the build files this package creates under tmp/work/?

```
bitbake systemd-journal-remote
ERROR: Nothing PROVIDES 'systemd-journal-remote'. Close matches:
    systemd RPROVIDES systemd-journal-remote
```

How do I run bitbake for just this package? (I am running Yocto Langdale)

Comment: Similar question, but with a little different focus: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67485708/include-systemd-journal-remote-with-bitbake

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the Yocto IRC for helping me with this! Here is the summary:

In general:

> bitbake builds recipes, not packages

Thus you cannot bitbake a package, you must bitbake the recipe - in my case `bitbake systemd` - and the package will be included (if enabled).

For `systemd-journal-remote` my mistake was that I did not set the correct `PACKAGECONFIG` thus not enabling this optional package:

> PACKAGECONFIG:append = " microhttpd"

Afterwards you can add the package to your image recipe:

> IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " systemd-journal-remote"